# How to prevent any of the stacked screens to show up during Flutter WillPopScope?

Tags: flutter, routes

I have a complex chain of form screens the user has to fill in.

The successive form screens are pushed to the navigator.

On each form screen "Continue" and "Later, save to draft" buttons allows the user to respectively push the next form screen or stop and come back later (he completes the draft later later on).

By tapping on the last screen "Return to the home screen" button or on "Later, save to draft", I route to the home screen by `popUntil` (The code I invoke is `_popAndGoToHome()`as follows:

```dart
  /// Head to home tab
  void _popAndGoToHome() {
    // Unfocus to make the keyboard disappear
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    //
    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

    // Swtich to gallery home tab
    AppMainScreenWithTabsState.bottomTabBarKey.currentState
        ?.goToGalleryHomeTab();
  }
```

As there are 10 screens, during the popping, one can quickly see some of the screens which is not something I want.

Is there a way to `popUntil` or land to the destination screen "instantaneously" — aka without seeing any screen bu the landing screen?